# How do I get WPA_GUI onto my pi without an ethernet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

The network here is wireless-only, and NOOBS/Raspbian install I have hasn't installed WPA_GUI.  The WiFi dongle I've got is the one from the RasPi store, and works on another Pi.  I could in theory edit wpa_supplicant.conf but it's enterprise WiFi and I'm not prepared to leave my password in a plain text file on a shared-use computer (the Pi).

So I'd like to download WPA_GUI on another machine (windows) and move it across by USB stick, but apparently that's not possible.  Alternatively I've got it on my personal Pi -- is it possible to shift it across?

Comment: So it turns out WPA_GUI writes the password to `wpa_supplicant.conf` in plain text anyway, without any option to not save it!

Answer (score 0):

On a third party computer download the driver install and setup. Run the file selecting a hard disk burn. And run disk on your computer. That's assuming that you can't download the driver separate and transfer it over.

Comment: I am not sure i follow your instructions

Comment: That just restates what I said in my question, only with less detail.